# How can I store temporary values?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, sqflite

I am implementing add to cart functionality, a user which is not login and adds multiple products to cart so where can I store this data, I am confused where can I store this cart data `Shared Preference` or `SQLite` or any other option provided by flutter?

And, when the user logged in all those products which are presented in the cart, will move to the user's personal cart. All the items will send to the server into my personal cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few storage options you can use with Flutter. As you pointed out, shared_preferences and SQLite are google options. Which you use just depends on what you are storing. As a rule of thumb, I store small data values, like settings, using shared_preferences. Meanwhile, larger data like cart information would be better off being stored with SQLite.

Comment: Ok, Sir, I understand but the point is I will send all the data from SQLite to the server into JSON format and I want all the items should be deleted after sending data to the server. When I logout no items should display into the local cart after sent to the server it will delete permanently.

Comment: You can use SQLite for that. Just store the quantities and product IDs in the database. When the user logs in, run some code to check for cart items. If there are any, push them to the server and delete from database.

Comment: Mean Cart Table will truncate

Comment: After send the data to server.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `SQLite`, I have also written an article using SQLite.

[Check here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/data-persistence-with-sqlite-flutter-47a6f67b973f)

Answer (score 1):

you can use one of the two plugins

1) flutter secure storage: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

2) shared_prefrences: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

this plugin is for basic saves,

if you want to save many things at a time then you can use the sqflite.

https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Answer (score 1):

**Flutter** makes these options available to us. Specifically:

1. Shared preferences
2. SQLite database
3. Text file

When you have small amounts of data that you want to persist across app runs, you can use Flutter's [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin to save that data.

In Flutter we can interact with an [SQLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) database through a plugin called SQFlite.

Not all data fits well in a database. Sometimes the easiest way to store it is in a file